# CSS: IE7 Selector

Tags: css, internet-explorer

How could I select IE7 with pure (valid) CSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to use a [conditional comment](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) (outside the CSS, e.g. defining a separare `<style>` section), the only thing you can use is CSS Hacks. See [here](http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks) for a "IE7 only" hack.

Comment: though eventually you'll have to hack the hack if they ever fix it

Comment: Yup. Conditional comments are way nicer.

Answer (score 3):

IE does support [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html), an IE-specific HTML comment syntax. You can use them to include IE7-specific CSS, e.g.

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

There’s no equivalent in CSS, unfortunately. But, as mentioned in other answers, there are some valid CSS hacks you can use to target CSS rules as just IE 7.

I personally prefer the conditional comment syntax as it’s a bit more explicit, but you can make the hacks explicit with comments.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want a separate stylesheet for IE hacks, here's another way doing it with using conditional comments:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]><body class="ie6"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 7)&(lt IE 8)]><body class="ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 8]><!--><body><!--<![endif]-->
    ...page content...
</body>
```

This give IE6, IE7 and [all other browsers] a different body element class. Now you can write rules like:

```
body.ie7 div.scroll { padding-bottom: 16px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

are expressions valid? if so:

```
cssAttr: expression( /msie 7/i.test( navigator.userAgent ) ? '#ie7val' : '#0th3r1' );
```

I highly doubt they are though, and technically that's CSS, but it's really JavaScript in disguise!

Comment: No, unfortunately they’re not valid CSS.

Comment: Figured, almost anything MS does tends to disagree with the W3C

Answer (score 0):

IE7-Only css jack:

```
*:first-child+html{ }
```